# Extraer datos de una tabla web con Chromium desde Delphi

Tags: html-tabla, navegador-web, delphi-tokyo

Primero, aclaro que soy novatillo en Delphi y estoy algo perdido. Necesito extraer los datos de una web y ponerlos en un StringGrid. La web en cuestión contiene varias tablas y solo necesito los datos de una por lo que, en principio, creo que necesitaría extraer todo el source code HTML de la web para seleccionar los datos que me interesan. Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo, es decir, cómo extraer el HTML? Tendría que almacenar el HTML en un memo para parsearlo? Estoy usando Chromium embedded.

Comment: Está solucionado. Ya tengo el HTML del frame, que era lo que me hacía falta.